# My app button won't work

Tags: java, android, android-button

I'm trying to create an app that, on the press of a button, changes the displayed text. However it doesn't work. I have checked my code, bit I don't see anything wrong with my event handler. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       //Reference Button
        Button ekeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ekeButton);

        ekeButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        TextView displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayText);
                        displayText.setText(R.string.NewMassage);

                    }
                }
        );

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my updated code:

```
    package com.mesoft.eventhandler;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       //Reference Button
        Button ekeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ekeButton);
        final TextView displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayText);


        ekeButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        displayText.setText(getString(R.string.NewMassage));

                    }
                }
        );



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and i declared my string in my string.xml
Here is the code:

```
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">Event Handler</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="click">Choose Massage</string>
    <string name="ShowMassage">Merry Xmas</string>
    <string name="NewMassage">Happy new year</string>
</resources>
```

here is activity_main.xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/ShowMassage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/displayText" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/click"
        android:id="@+id/ekeButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/displayText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/displayText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/displayText"
        android:textColor="#090909" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What error do you get ? (if any)

Comment: Use `getResources().getString(R.string.NewMassage)` instead of `getString(R.string.NewMassage)`

Comment: remove `android:enabled="false"` from your `<Button>` in your layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this,

```
displayText.setText(R.string.NewMassage);
```

with

```
displayText.setText(getString(R.string.NewMassage));
```

And also,

Its better to declare

```
TextView displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayText);
```

outside `onClick()` method. I mean below

```
Button ekeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ekeButton);
```

> **Note:** make sure you have declared `NewMassage` in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="NewMassage">Text you want to display</string>
```

Comment: I replaced the code as you suggested and declared "TextView" outside "onClick" but it still did not work. I don't know what else to do...

Comment: Try replacing `displayText` line too

Comment: with what? or how do i replace it

Comment: Update your code. That's what i am saying. `displayText.setText(R.string.NewMassage);` is wrong. Remove that line. And add `displayText.setText(getString(R.string.NewMassage));`

Comment: yes i have done that already as you suggested earlier...replaced "displayText" line with displayText.setText(getString(R.string.NewMassage) ); but my button is still not working.

Comment: OK. It does not give me any error...except for if i run the app on my phone the button don't work

Comment: try adding this `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` below `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Please check, i have past my activity_main.xml code. And i try adding Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); setSupportActionBar(toolbar); below setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); As you suggested it still did not work...

Comment: I don't understand why its not working. May be try removing `final` from `final TextView displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayText);`

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
displayText.setText(R.string.NewMassage);
```

with

```
displayText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.NewMassage));
```

`R.string.NewMassage` returns an id of `NewMassage` String resource in form of an `Integer`.

And also as said by [activesince93](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110234/activesince93), declare your textView outside button OnclickListener